# How to create a tool bar using jquery mobile in android phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using cardova 2.9.0,  How can I create a fixed toolbar just below the header. which is is similar to the Facebook application as highlighted in below image,

[image]

I need the fixed toolbar, How can I create that? Suggest me Any plugins or any other efficient way to get the fixed tool bar.

Comment: check now http://jsfiddle.net/y4e6S/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed toolbar try like following:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">      
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div>
```

Refer this for fixed Header and Footer   [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4e6S/11/)

Comment: But there is a space between header to fixed top grid bar. The grid bar should attached to header as shown in above image. Do we need any plugins

Comment: I need the same, But Why do you use the css for that, .top is not there in html right

Comment: i thought you need the content to be fixed so that s why i use CSS. i  forget to remove that Now is that okay.http://jsfiddle.net/y4e6S/11/